# Unable to stop my application from going back to login activity no matter what i do

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, start-activity

This is giving me a hard time, no matter what i do pressing back button return the application to login activity.

These are the methods is I've tried so far:

1: I tried to set intent flags to clear top, erase history and also exclude the activity from recents.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NoticeAndStuff.class);
intent.addFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS | intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

2: I also tried using finish() after the startActivity() call.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NoticeAndStuff.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Needless to say I also tried both of them at the same time too, and also tried setting the noHistory flag in manifest file just to be sure. I tried overriding the back button too, yet the back button returns to the login activity.

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name=".app.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NoticeAndStuff"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_notice_and_stuff"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Subscriptions"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_subscriptions"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Details"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_details"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Abouts"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_abouts"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FeedBack"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_feed_back"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: have you tried, setActivityForResult? also is NoticeAndStuff the class you want to go to?

Comment: Once you've finished the activity there is no way you can go back to the previous activity unless you are explicitly starting that activity on back pressed.

Comment: use finish() before startActivity(intent)

Comment: @Anil it wont start the activity `NoticeAndStuff` then

Comment: Show your backpress code if you have added something in that

Comment: then explicitly handle back button event

Comment: @MohamedSalad I'm afraid I'm unknown to that method, would you please elaborate. And yes NoticeAndStuff is the class i want to go to. Once I'm at NoticeAndStuff pressing back button returns to the login class.

Comment: @camelCaseCoder 
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        //moveTaskToBack(true);
        if(count == 1)
        {
            count=0;
            finish();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Press Back again to quit.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            count++;
        }

        return;
    }

Comment: the login activity is the MainActivity?

Comment: @Anil please checkout the above comment

Comment: @Anil please elaborate on explicitly handling the back buttton event

Comment: @RenanLopesFerreira yes The MainActivity is the login activity too lazy to change the name :D

Comment: the code looks fine , can you add your manifest in the question too. I think you have set the parent activity tag.

Comment: @AllayKhalil Just added my manifest file. please check

Comment: where is the Login Activity in the Manifest

Comment: @AllayKhalil <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
Intent intent =new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: are you calling that activity somewhere else ? Please post whole code

Comment: I am not. I don't think posting the whole code will solve this. Its way to big and my question content look bulky.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your manifest should have details like his

```
    <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.SplashScreen">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
<activity
            android:name=".NoticeAndStuff"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

And MainActivity should be class Extending Activity class or AppCompatActivity
And the navigation to next screen will be

```
void moveToNextScreen(){
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NoticeAndStuff.class));
        this.finish();
    }
```

If then make sure your build files are cleaned and rebuild every time you make a code change. In Android studio it will be "Drive Path\AppName\app\build" You can manually delete and try clean build again. Apart from these there may not be any errors.

**Edit:** If all these are not working , then put this on your backbutton press

```
finishAffinity();
```

Check this for deails: [API Details](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAffinity())

> Finish this activity as well as all activities immediately below it in
>   the current task that have the same affinity. This is typically used
>   when an application can be launched on to another task (such as from
>   an ACTION_VIEW of a content type it understands) and the user has used
>   the up navigation to switch out of the current task and in to its own
>   task. In this case, if the user has navigated down into any other
>   activities of the second application, all of those should be removed
>   from the original task as part of the task switch.
>
> Note that this finish does not allow you to deliver results to the
>   previous activity, and an exception will be thrown if you are trying
>   to do so.

Comment: Try these and if this is still not feasible, let me know I can give one more solution

Comment: The MainActivity is not the launcher activity so i'm afraid the launcher this in manifest is not doable. I did try that though but it didn't work.

Comment: I just given a sample and may be different according to our implementation. So your splashscreen also should be removed by calling finish? Similar is the case for NoticeAndStuff. Try with new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NoticeAndStuff.class)  , Before that clean and rebuild as I have mentioned.

Comment: I'm using usb debugging and running application in my cellphone. Do i still need to clear that?

Comment: I cleaned it anyway but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks finishAffinity(); did the trick, you sir are awesome :D

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this
  Intent ii2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FacebookSharing.class);
                ii2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(ii2);
                finish();
```

Comment: Tried that. Problem still exits.

Answer (score 1):

I think that all thing is good, just try this which you have already done.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NoticeAndStuff.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

but I think you need to uninstall the app from your device. Then before building and running again on the device clean and rebuild the project. Then Run the app and then let us know if it is the same result.

Comment: Tried doing everything you said, Still the problem exists.

Answer (score 1):

It is little bit tricky, Try this.

> Using **FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** and **FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK** will do the
>   trick

```
Intent next = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        // will close all the running activiities and goes to Login Activity
next.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(next);
finish();
```

Happy Coding..!!

Answer (score 1):

In a worst case scenario try

```
ActivityCompat.finishAffinity();
```

This will destroy the current activity without any trace, no intents can passed to other activity if this is done.

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:noHistory="true"`  where your login activity is declared in `manifest.xml`

If that is not working, try

```
Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, NoticeAndStuff.class);
i.setFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
finish();
startActivity(i);
```